# Angular Material Auto Complete Not Changing

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I have two text boxes. One is for category. Another is for category values. Textbox 1 is dropdown and Textbox 2 is Auto Complete.

**My Array**

```
[{"name":"A", "value":1},
{"name":"A", "value":2},
{"name":"A", "value":3},
{"name":"B", "value":4},
{"name":"B", "value":5},
{"name":"B", "value":6}]
```

**Code**

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="lName" name="Lname" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="name">
                      <option value="A">A</option>
                      <option value="B">B</option>
                    </select>
           <input   [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
                          {{option}}
                        </mat-option>
                      </mat-autocomplete>
```

**TS**

```
    myControl = new FormControl();
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
  }

 onChange(value){
     var result = this.lookup_report.filter(obj => {
          if(obj.name=== value){
return obj.value;
}
        })
    }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return result.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

My problem is when I enter `A` I could get the value `1,2,3` and I am clear them. Again I am entering `B`, the second textbox auto populates `1,2,3`. I don't need them to carry over When I entering different name. If I enter 4 on auto complete then it is showing the values for `B`